# $\max _{w \in \mathbb{R}^{m}: w \neq 0} \frac{ |w A|}{|w|} \leq \max _{v \in \mathbb{R}^{n}: v \neq 0} \frac{ |A v|}{|v|}$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $A$ be an mxn matrix. Prove that $\max _{w \in \mathbb{R}^{m}: w \neq 0} \frac{ |w A|}{|w|} \leq \max _{v \in \mathbb{R}^{n}: v \neq 0} \frac{ |A v|}{|v|}$

As $|x|^2 = x^Tx$, I applied this to $|wA|$:
$|wA|^2 = (wA)^T(wA) =  A^T w^T  wA = A^T |w|^2 A = |w|^2 A^T A$.

Therefore

$\max _{w \in \mathbb{R}^{m}: w \neq 0} \frac{ |w A|}{|w|}  = \max _{w \in \mathbb{R}^{m}: w \neq 0} \frac{|w| \sqrt{A^T A}}{ |w|} = \sqrt{A^T A} $

Looking then on the right hand side of the inequality in the question:

$\max _{v \in \mathbb{R}^{n}: v \neq 0} \frac{ |A v|}{|v|} = \max _{v \in \mathbb{R}^{n}: v \neq 0} \frac{ \sqrt{v^T A^T A v}}{|v|}$

I'm unsure how to go further though? Is it true that

$ \sqrt{A^T A} \leq  \max _{v \in \mathbb{R}^{n}: v \neq 0} \frac{ \sqrt{v^T A^T A v}}{|v|}$

If so, why?

Comment: Is there any relation between $m$ and $n$, like $m\le n$?

Comment: What is $\sqrt{A^TA}$? If $A$ is $m \times n$ then $A^TA$ is $n \times n$.  $|x|^2 = x^Tx$ works for column vectors $x \in M_{n1}$, so that $x^Tx$ is indeed a scalar. In that case $wA \in M_{1n}$ so the formula should be $(wA)(wA)^T$.

Answer (score 1):

I think the inequality is actually an equality, the reasons are as follows:

Do the singular value decomposition: $A=USV$, where $U\in O(m),V\in O(n) $ and $S$ is a diagonal matrix with the diagonal elements being the singular values of $A$. Then you can see
$$ \max _{w \in \mathbb{R}_{m}: w \neq 0} \frac{ |w A|}{|w|} = \max _{w \in \mathbb{R}_{m}: w \neq 0} \frac{ |wUS|}{|wU|} = \max _{w \in \mathbb{R}_{m}: w \neq 0} \frac{ |wS|}{|w|}$$
and 
$$ \max _{v \in \mathbb{R}^{n}: v \neq 0} \frac{ | Av|}{|v|} = \max _{v \in \mathbb{R}^{n}: v \neq 0} \frac{ |SVv|}{|Vv|}=\max _{v \in \mathbb{R}^{n}: v \neq 0} \frac{ |S v|}{|v|} ,$$
both of which are equal to the maximal absolute value of the singular value of $A$.